# SQL Check if a new store group was added, then flag their stores accordingly

Tags: sql

I have a doubt about how to properly case flag some items in my query. I have a table with data starting from 08/2019, like the following:

```
Store Group |Store Owner| Store | Date
     GA     |     AA    |   A   |06/2019
     GA     |     AA    |   A   |07/2019
     GA     |     AA    |   B   |06/2019
     GA     |     AA    |   B   |07/2019
```

I then needed to flag when a new store was added, disregarding month 8. So I managed to create the following code, which can flag when a store was added:

```
SELECT "STORE GROUP", "STORE OWNER", "STORE", TO_CHAR(TO_DATE("DATE"), 'MM/YYYY') "DATE","FLAG" FROM 

(
SELECT
 a."STORE GROUP", a. "STORE OWNER", a."STORE" , CONCAT (min(a."datemonth" ), '01') "DATE", 
CASE 
WHEN a."datemonth" = '201908'
THEN 'INITIAL'
ELSE 'STORE ADDED'
END
AS "FLAG"
FROM
  "TABLE" as a

  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT
 "STORE GROUP", "STORE OWNER", "STORE", "datemonth"
FROM "TABLE") as b
on b."STORE" = a."STORE" and b."STORE OWNER" = a."STORE OWNER" and a."datemonth"!= b."datemonth"
group by a."STORE GROUP",a."STORE OWNER", a."STORE", a."datemonth"
)
```

Now the problem is, as the months goes by, a new STORE OWNER, with many different STORES, can be added to this table. I then needed to flag these new entries from this STORE OWNER as "INITIAL" on the first month in which they appeared. And after that, if a new store is added to this new STORE GROUP, flag then as "STORE ADDED".

How could I do that?

Eample how it should lile:

```
   Store Group     |Store Owner     |   Store | Date        | FLAG
    GA             |     AA         |   A     |06/2019      | INITIAL
    GA             |     AA         |   B     |06/2019      | INITIAL
    GA             |     AA         |   C     |06/2019      | INITIAL
    GA             |     AA         |   BB    |07/2019      | NEW STORE
```

Comment: This does not look like MySQL syntax. Are you sure that this is the database that you are using?

Comment: hi, It's sqlscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `row_number()` to check whether the current record is the earliest for the given `store_owner` (or `store`), and set the flag accordingly:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case 
        when rank() over(partition by store_owner order by date) = 1
            then 'Initial'
            else 'Store added'
    end as status_flag 
from mytable t
```

This asssumes that you are storing dates using the `date` datatype, and that dates are all aligned on the first day of the month. Otherwise we need a little tweak:

```
    case 
        when rank() over(partition by store_owner order by year(date), month(date)) = 1
            then 'Initial'
            else 'Store added'
    end as status_flag
```

Comment: Hi! This is a nice idea! But it's not working, it's tagging everything as NEW. Any idea why?

Comment: @Renato: what is `'NEW'`? The query producs `'Initial'` or `'Store added'` only.

Comment: Initial should be only on the first month a new store owner was added. New should be any new stores added after the first month under the same store owner.

I added an example of how it should beahave on the main topic

Comment: @Renato: I updated my answer as per your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(date) over (partition by store) > '2019-08-01'
             then 'New' else 'Existing'
        end)
from t;
```

This assumes that the column called `date` is actually stored as a date.

Comment: I see, thanks for that, but this doesn't really helps me with my main problem

Comment: @Renato . . . This appears to do what you are asking for, so I'm not sure why you say it doesn't help.

Comment: This code does something similar to my original code did. But the problem is when a new store owner is added as the months goes by. The new stores that belong to this new store owner should be flagged as Initial. Your code flag all stores witth data above 082019 as  new.